# Rail Joins Syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `join` statement which I am writing like such:

```
   SomeTable.joins(<<-SQL)
     INNER JOIN TableA as a
             ON a.id = SomeTable.id
     WHERE
           a.user_id = #{user_id}    
   SQL
```

Is there a way to write this where `#{user_id}` is parameterized? Or do I have to use a different syntax?

I would like to prevent SQL injection by doing something like `.where(user_id: ?, user_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
 SomeTable.joins(:table_a).where("user_id = ?", user_id)
```

Assuming that your models are:

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :table_as
 end

 class TableA < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
   has_many :some_tables
 end

 class SomeTable < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :table_a
 end
```